# Extracting values from a joined RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two lists like:

```
Hourly_Sports,DEF (show,channel)
Hourly_Sports,21  (show,views)
```

I've split strings and rearranged them using code :

```
def split_show_views(line):
    show,views=line.split(',')
    return (show, views)   
show_views = show_views_file.map(split_show_views)
def split_show_channel(line):
     show,channel=line.split(',')
     return (show, channel)
show_channel = show_channel_file.map(split_show_channel)
     joined_dataset = show_views.join(show_channel)
```

Now when i call "collect" the list looks like:

```
(u'Baked_Talking', (u'MAN', u'138'))
```

and now I want only the "channel" and "view part"
The instruction is:

```
def extract_channel_views(show_views_channel): 
    <INSERT_CODE_HERE>
    return (channel, views)
```

It seems that the joined list consists split strings already so I can't use the "split" function again, and I've checked with the python built-in functions but did not find any extract function? It seems to me that "channel" and "views" are defined in the previous steps, so I don't have to add anything? If it's not, how can I define channel and views? I tried something like `show,channel,views=split('',('',''))`, I don't think it's right but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: In your example you have a list `(u'Baked_Talking', (u'MAN', u'138'))` what parts of this list are you trying to extract?

Comment: I want channel and views,so  in the example I provided, it would be MAN and 138

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing you can do is to use `values` method:

```
joined_dataset.values()
```

but if you really want a separate function then all you have to know is that elements of the output RDD are plain Python `tuples`. It means you can use `getitem`:

```
def extract_channel_views(show_views_channel):
    return show_views_channel[1]
```

or unpack:

```
def extract_channel_views(show_views_channel):
    _, (channel, views) = show_views_channel
    return channel, views
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think the third one is easier for me to understand since i'm a beginner and i have to stick with what has been  taught, but the first one is also pretty smart and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these will work for what you want:

```
def extract_channel_views(svc): 
    views = svc[1][0]
    channel = svc[1][1]
    return (channel, views)
```

or

```
def extract_channel_views(svc): 
    cv = svc[1]
    views = cv[1]
    channel = cv[0]
    return (channel, views)
```